# Recommendations on configurable resources in UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to hear some advice regarding resources and `UserControls`...

I realized that `UserControls` sometimes have properties which I want to be configurable - but on a **global scale** and **not per-instance**.

Let me give you an example:

I have implemented a `UserControl` which basically represents a tab (I call it `RibbonTab`):

[RibbonTab Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYUpd.png)

Each tab has its own icon and text (and some other properties) which are all `DependencyProperties`, so I can instantiate my tabs like this:

```
<!-- Time Tracking Tab -->
<UserControls:RibbonTab
     Icon="{StaticResource TimeTrackingTabIcon}"
     Text="{StaticResource TimeTrackingTabHeaderString}"
     LabelMode="AutoResize" ResizePriority="0"
     Command="{Binding LoadTimeTrackingViewModelCommand}"/>

<!-- Vacation Tab -->
<UserControls:RibbonTab
     Icon="{StaticResource VacationTabIcon}"
     Text="{StaticResource VacationTabHeaderString}"
     LabelMode="AutoResize" ResizePriority="1"
     Command="{Binding LoadVacationViewModelCommand}"/>

<!-- Payout Tab -->
<UserControls:RibbonTab
     Icon="{StaticResource PayoutTabIcon}"
     Text="{StaticResource PayoutTabHeaderString}"
     LabelMode="AutoResize" ResizePriority="2"
     Command="{Binding LoadPayoutViewModelCommand}"/>
```

As you can see, the background color of the selected tab is white. This is currently a fixed value within the `ControlTemplate`. I'd like this to be configurable instead.

I figured out various possible solutions, but I'm uncertain if I overthink:

**1.) Use a DependencyProperty**

I could introduce another `DependencyProperty` like `"SelectedTabColor"` and instantiate the tabs like this:

```
<!-- Time Tracking Tab -->
<UserControls:RibbonTab
     <!-- All of the previous properties go here... -->
     SelectedTabColor="White"/>

<!-- Vacation Tab -->
<UserControls:RibbonTab
     <!-- All of the previous properties go here... -->
     SelectedTabColor="White"/>

<!-- Payout Tab -->
<UserControls:RibbonTab
     <!-- All of the previous properties go here... -->
     SelectedTabColor="White"/>
```

It's easy to see that this technique requires to attach values over and over again, but you really just want to set this property once (globally) and be done.

**2.) Use a ResourceDictionary**

I could make my `UserControl` reference a `StaticResource` from the application's `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.View.UserControls.RibbonTab">
    <Grid>

        <!-- Lots of stuff omitted here... -->

        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource RibbonTab_SelectedTabColor}"/>

        <!-- More stuff omitted here... -->

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But then my `UserControl` requires the application/integration to have a `StaticResource` which is named exactly like this. Porting the `UserControl` to another project would be a nightmare...

**3.) Use UserControl.Resources + StaticResources**

Another possibility is to utilize the `Resources` attribute of the `UserControl` and place its required definitions as `StaticResources` directly there:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.View.UserControls.RibbonTab">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <!--#region Configurable properties -->

        <Color x:Key="SelectedTabColor">White</Color>

        <!--#endregion Configurable properties -->

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <!-- Lots of stuff omitted here... -->

        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource SelectedTabColor}"/>

        <!-- More stuff omitted here... -->

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This has a nice touch since each `StaticResource` is stored together with the element which actually uses it, instead of having a large `ResourceDictionary` and losing tracking of what is used where.

However, the drawback is that you can't reuse a common definition (let's say the application defines a certain accent color in its `ResourceDictionary`) across multiple `UserControls`, but have to redefine it everywhere, which makes it hard to maintain.

**4.) Use UserControl.Resources + ResourceKeys**

The best approach I could come up with so far is to define `StaticResources` with `ResourceKeys` (instead of the actual values) in the `Resources` of the `UserControl`. The integrator has to set the `ResourceKeys` to the application's existing resources:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.View.UserControls.RibbonTab">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <!--#region Configurable properties -->
        <!-- Integration hint: Set ResourceKey to your own definition! -->

        <StaticResource x:Key="SelectedTabColor"
             ResourceKey="AppHighlightedElementAccentColor"/>

        <!--#endregion Configurable properties -->

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <!-- Lots of stuff omitted here... -->

        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource SelectedTabColor}"/>

        <!-- More stuff omitted here... -->

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have not evaluated this in detail, yet. The only drawback I can see right now is that the type of the referenced resource is checked only at runtime but not at design time.

---

Am I missing the obvious...? Is there maybe an elegant way to solve this issue? Would be great to hear some opinions, because by now I'm a bit uncertain on how to proceed...

Comment: I'd likely do something with a `DynamicResource`. Then write code somewhere to update the resource in the ResourceDictionary where it lives. A resource is a resource is a resource (more or less), but `StaticResource` retrieves the value of the resource exactly once, when the XAML is loaded. [`DynamicResource`, however](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension), sticks around, monitors the resource dictionary, and updates the dependency property if the resource's value changes. Very handy for "theming" stuff like this.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand your advice correctly. Are you suggesting to use a DependencyProperty nevertheless, even though it means having to assign the same value for each instance of the UserControl?

Comment: Use DynamicResource. Who told you that Rectangle.Fill is not a dependency property? Why did you not just look it up, or try it? Anyway, read my comment again explaining what DynamicResource does, and click on the link to MSDN.

Comment: I guess my question is poorly worded and doesn't get my point across at all... Thanks for the effort, anyway!

Comment: The question is clear and I answered it. Can you help me understand why you object to using `DynamicResource`?

Comment: I'm not objecting `DynamicResource`, but I fail to see how the dynamic look-up and update behavior makes a difference in the four scenarios that I was able to come up with. Also, I'm not sure about your comment "Who told you that Rectangle.Fill is not a dependency property?" and where I implied that this was my understanding. Many apologies.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question after all. My impression was that you wanted a simple way to change the background brush (in practice, this means the Fill property of your Rectangle) for all existing instances of a given UserControl, all together at once. That's very simply done. What are you trying to do instead?